# couchDB views inaccessible while updating

Tags: view, couchdb

Sorry I couldn't think of a more descriptive title: We have an issue with updating couchDB views since they're inaccessible while the design doc is being reindexed.  Is the only solution to allow stale views?

In one scenario, there are several couchDB nodes which replicate with each other.  Updating a view in one will cause all couchDB nodes to reindex the design doc.  Is it not possible to update the view on one node and then replicate out the result?  I assume the issue there is that new docs could be inserted into other nodes while the one is reindexing.

In another scenario, we have several couchDB nodes which are read/write and replicate with each other.  For web apps, there's another cluster with read-only couchDB nodes... they don't replicate out, but are replicated to from the read/write pool.  A solution here could be to take a node out of the cluster, update the view and wait for it to reindex. However, won't that node be missing any documents that were created during reindexing?  Is it possible for it to continue receiving document inserts while reindexing?

Are there other possible solutions?  We're migrating to the second scenario, so that's what I'm primarily concerned with, but I'm wondering if there's a general solution for either case.  Using stale views isn't an ideal scenario since reindexing can take a long time and it's a high-traffic site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's great to hear that you are having success with CouchDB.

I suggest you use the [staging-and-upgrade technique](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/How_to_deploy_view_changes_in_a_live_environment) described in the wiki. It requires a little preparation to get working, however once you have it working, it works very well without any human effort.